# NHS free prescriptions

Tags: medications

If the UK National Health Service offers free prescriptions to certain groups of society, How is the medicine payed for ?

My question is do the various drug companies have a 'deal' with the NHS to offer lower priced drugs for NHS use, and what is that deal exactly ?

Comment: You do not necessarily get free prescriptions just because you are disabled.  See https://www.nhs.uk/using-the-nhs/help-with-health-costs/get-help-with-prescription-costs

Comment: I'm not questioning peoples eligibility for free prescriptions, I'm asking for a breakdown of how free prescriptions are paid for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a political question, not about health.

Comment: Thanks Carey, have moved the question to the political stack exchange.